# Cucumber Setup in Eclipse

Tags: cucumber

Hi I am new to Cucumber ad trying to setup the framework.I have created the feature file, TestRunner class and the StepDefinition file but getting the below error on JUnit console.

I am sharing the project structure and the files[![Project Structure[[image: FeatureFileStepDefinitionTestRunnnerFile]

Comment: Console Error is

Comment: io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step "I navigate to Login page" is undefined. You can implement it using the snippet(s) below:

@Given("I navigate to Login page")
public void i_navigate_to_login_page() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have already implemented your step definitions (I cannot tell from the provided info), this Exception means that Cucumber cannot find your step definitions.

From the [Cucumber FAQ](https://cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/):

"If Cucumber is telling you that your steps are undefined, when you have defined step definitions, this means that Cucumber cannot find your step definitions. You’ll need to make sure to specify the path to your step definitions (glue path) correctly.

By default Cucumber-JVM will search in the package (or sub-packages) of the runner class. You can also tell Cucumber-JVM explicitly which packages (and sub-packages) to search, with:

```
 @CucumberOptions(glue = ["<package>", "<package>", "<etc>"])
 class RunCucumberTest
```

"